# First non-zero eigenvalue of the Laplacian

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, riemannian-geometry, riemann-surfaces

Consider the Laplacian $-\Delta$ on a compact Riemann surface of genus $g \geq 2$. Is there an upper bound on the multiplicity of the first non-zero eigenvalue of the Laplacian? In particular, does it have to be simple?

Comment: [This notes](https://math.berkeley.edu/~alanw/240papers03/vitocruz.pdf) give a bound, refering to [N. Nadirashvili. Multiple eigenvalues of the Laplace operator. Math USSR
Sbornik, 61(1):225–238, 1988] for details.